# The given data was not valid JSON

Tags: swift, swiftui

When I make a curl request in the terminal using just the URL it works fine, however when I try to do it using URLSession it fails and no data seems to be retrieved.

My JSON structure is like:

```
{
  "access_token": "x123",
  "expires_in": 3599,
  "scope": "x123",
  "token_type": "Bearer"
}
```

Here is my service file:

```
struct Welcome: Codable {
    let tokens: [Token]
}

struct Token: Codable {
    let accessToken: String
    let expiresIn: String
    let scope: String
    let tokenType: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case accessToken = "access_token"
        case expiresIn = "expires_in"
        case scope
        case tokenType = "token_type"
    }
}

class RefreshToken: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var refreshToken = [Token]()
    
    func getRefresh() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "url-redacted") else {return}
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (theData, response, error) in
            guard error == nil else {print(error!.localizedDescription); return }
            // guard let data = data else {print("empty data"); return }

            let theData = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Welcome.self, from: theData!)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.refreshToken = theData.tokens
                
            }
            
        }
        .resume()
}

}
```

As I said when using terminal with a curl request the response is fine, but with `URLSession` it fails, my file can Build but it exits after build with the error message `The given data was not valid JSON`

Comment: Have you tried reading the contents of `theData` converted to a UTF8 String?

Comment: You should not use `try!` in situations which can fail. You should prefer a proper `do { try ... } catch { print(error) // handle error }`. That would also give you the actual error description.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez I am not sure what steps to take to do that?

Answer (score 4):

Why do you decode as `Welcome` if the json returns a `Token`?
Try to decode as `Token.self`

And also, the json seems to return `expires_in` as `Int` while you declared:

```swift
let expiresIn: String // -> This should be Int
```